# Как найти работу или стартап?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, работа

На протяжении полугода изучаю веб-программирование, в частности: html, css, js, vue, php и так далее. Имеется желание вступить в startup, но никак не могу найти место, где взяли бы в команду новичка. Можете что-то посоветовать, кто сталкивался с этим на начале своего пути?

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте придумать себе какой-то проект и его реализовать, это может быть что угодно: от простого сайта показывающего что было в тот же день 50 лет назад (привет парсинг википедии), до чего-то большого с анимациями и продвинутым ксс, сложной сервер-сайд, например магазин.
Если же учится надоело да и денег свободных и лишних не много - ищите junior вакансию и вперёд трудится за 15-30 тысяч. Не много, но это опыт плюс возможность взаимодействия с более опытными коллегами и перенятия их навыков.